# Angular ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined- occurs using function

Tags: angular

The error occurs only when the code is formed in function otherwise there is no error.
When the isInvalidPage method is called, I get the ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined but if the method is not in a function then i don't get the error.

```
    // Error happens if isInvalidPage method is used
export class PaginationComponent implements OnChanges {
  pagerSource: any = {} || [];
  sourcePageSize = 10;
  pagedSources;
  @Input() paginationData;
  constructor(private pagerService: PagerService) {
    console.log('pagination service called');
  }
  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.paginationData) {
      this.setPage(1);
    }
  }
  setPage(page: number) {
    this.isInvalidPage(page);
    console.log('isinavlid', this.isInvalidPage(page));
    this.getPagerObject(page);
    this.getCurrentPage();
  }
  isInvalidPage(page) {
    if (page < 1 || page > this.pagerSource.totalPages || this.paginationData == null
      || this.paginationData.length === 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  getCurrentPage() {
    this.pagedSources = this.paginationData.slice(this.pagerSource.startRecordCount - 1,
      this.pagerSource.endRecordCount);
  }
  getPagerObject(page) {
    this.pagerSource = this.pagerService.getPager(this.paginationData.length, page,
      this.sourcePageSize);
  }
  onPageSizeChange(pageSize: number) {
    this.sourcePageSize = pageSize;
    this.setPage(1);
  }

}
```

// No error If isInvalidPage method is not used

```
export class PaginationComponent implements OnChanges {
  pagerSource: any = {} || [];
  sourcePageSize = 10;
  pagedSources;
  @Input() paginationData;
  constructor(private pagerService: PagerService) {
    console.log('pagination service called');
  }
  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.paginationData) {
      this.setPage(1);
    }
  }
  setPage(page: number) {
    if (page < 1 || page > this.pagerSource.totalPages || this.paginationData == null
      || this.paginationData.length === 0) {
        return;
    } // code implemented without function
    this.getPagerObject(page);
    this.getCurrentPage();
  }
  getCurrentPage() {
    this.pagedSources = this.paginationData.slice(this.pagerSource.startRecordCount - 1,
      this.pagerSource.endRecordCount);
  }
  getPagerObject(page) {
    this.pagerSource = this.pagerService.getPager(this.paginationData.length, page,
      this.sourcePageSize);
  }
  onPageSizeChange(pageSize: number) {
    this.sourcePageSize = pageSize;
    this.setPage(1);
  }

}
```

Comment: What type of data is `paginationData`? Number, array of numbers, etc?

Comment: array of object

Comment: Try this `@Input() paginationData = [];`. If the objects are mapped to a class `@Input() paginationData: ClassName[] = [];`. Sometimes `undefined` error throws if you have a instanciated the variable.

Comment: but the error occurs only if i call a piece of code in a function otherwise no error.

Comment: That's probably because you're trying to access a variable that's either not instantiated or has no value. By adding `= []` you instantiate it object of empty resulting your case to return `0`.

Comment: I tried it but still dint work.

Comment: Ok, I've been looking at the wrong method all this time. I don't think you can use `null` or `.length === 0` at the same level like that. I think you need to use that like `if` within `if` format for it to work. Or with `&&` instead `||`. `this.paginationData == null
      && this.paginationData.length > 0`

Comment: where do you mean?

Comment: In the `isInvalidPage` method. You can try logic up to `null` as first `if` then `.length` as `if` within that first `if`.

Comment: could be nice if you can write what you mean :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Jotas answer worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shouldnt this be:

```
setPage(page: number) {
    if(!this.isInvalidPage(page)){
     console.log('isinavlid', this.isInvalidPage(page));
     this.getPagerObject(page);
     this.getCurrentPage();
   };    
  }
```

thats basically what you do in the version with no `isInvalidPage` method